# "TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating  n number of students name but I can't . My source code is:

```
n= input ("enter number of students")
for I in range(0,n):
    Stud_name=input ("enter the name of students")
    Print(stud_name)
```

Comment: Try `print(repr(n))` ... its a string, but the `range` function needs an integer. `n = int(n)` fixes it.... as long as the user really entered a decimal string.

Comment: also print should be lowercase

Comment: and ```Stud_name``` should be lowercase to match it's other usage

Answer (score 2):

Users enter text and the program needs to parse that into an integer. Accounting for users who can't follow simple instructions...

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("Enter number of students: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number")

for i in range(1, n+1):
    stud_name = input("Enter the name of student {}: ".format(i))
    print(stud_name)
```