# Why there is a TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a practice of OrderedDict. I am trying to assign value to dictionary by using input().rsplit method. There is an error occurred called:"TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". Where did I get wrong?

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
num=input()
itemlist=OrderedDict()
for i in range(num):
    itemName,itemPrice=input().rsplit(' ',1)
    if itemName in itemlist:
        itemlist[itemName] += int(itemPrice)
    else:
        itemlist[itemName] = int(itemPrice)
for name, price in itemlist.items():
    print str(name), str(price)
```

I expect to store user's input to the dictionary like 'BANANA FRIES 12'

Here is the example of OrderedDict

```
ordered_dictionary = OrderedDict()
>>> ordered_dictionary['a'] = 1
>>> ordered_dictionary['b'] = 2
>>> ordered_dictionary['c'] = 3
>>> ordered_dictionary['d'] = 4
>>> ordered_dictionary['e'] = 5
>>> 
>>> print ordered_dictionary
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5)])
```

This error seems to tell me cannot assign itemPrice to itemlist[itemName]...I don't know why

Comment: `num=input()` should be `num=int(input())`. If that's not it, you need to make a [mre] and include the full error message with traceback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50403732/4518341)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403732/typeerror-str-object-cannot-be-interpreted-as-an-integer)

Answer (score 1):

`num=input()` reads value from user and is of type string. You have to convert it to integer before using it with `range`

So, it should be :

```
num = int(input())
```